# org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions some methods seem not reliable, How to deal with it?

Tags: java, selenium

Here are my codes:

```
@FindBy(id = 'save')
private WebElement saveBtn;

public void clickSaveBtn() {
    WebDriverWait waiter = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5, 200);
    waiter.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("save")));
    waiter.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("save")));
    saveBtn.click();
}
```

if code like above, selenium always said:current element is not clickable
but if i add some sleep before click, it works.

```
    public void clickSaveBtn() {
        WebDriverWait waiter = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5, 200);
        waiter.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("save")));
        waiter.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("save")));
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        saveBtn.click();
    }
```

why? the method elementToBeClickable() is not reliable?

Comment: Could you share exact error stacktrace??

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (1112, 195). Other element would receive the click: <div id="j6wPr9" class="notifierEntry z-div">...</div>

Comment: @Dale Many of the Automation test scripts always require `Thread.sleep(XXXX)` to run perfectly. Neither of presenceOfElementLocated nor elementToBeClickable will work

Comment: thanks, that question has been solved